# How do you make Cuphead black and white?

Tags: cuphead

I've seen screenshots of it, and a character on the third isle says something about you have to be a pacifist or something. How is it done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You unlock it by beating all of the run and gun (non-boss) levels with a pacifist rank (without shooting or killing any enemies).

For those levels that you have achieved the rank on, a flag with a "P" will be where you enter the level.

[image: Pacifist flag]

Comment: Correct me if I am not remembering correctly, don't you have to talk to the turtle as well to get the option after you've completed the levels with the P ranking?

Comment: There are some alternatives using external tools (including windows itself). Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/157340/how-to-make-my-display-grayscale

Answer (score 6):

In Inkwell Isle 3, there's a turtle near the port by Cala Maria. After you get Pacifist rank on all 6 Run 'n Guns (you get P rank by successfully completing a Run 'n Gun without shooting or killing any of the enemies), talk to the turtle. He will grant you an option in settings: visual, for black and white.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! On this network, it is advised not to add an answer that has information that is already covered by another one.

Comment: @Tiimzy The earlier answer doesn't mention the turtle, and doesn't provide as many specific details as this one does. If a new answer *adds* something relevant that others missed, it shouldn't matter if there's some overlap.

Comment: OK. Sorry about that. I didn't know. :)